# Connect active directory with the support of ssl (ldaps)

Tags: java, ssl, active-directory, keystore, truststore

am trying to connect with active directory with the support of ssl.

i tried the steps from following web site.

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Configuring+an+SSL+Certificate+for+Microsoft+Active+Directory

when i try to connect active directory from the java code it gives following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind fail
ed: 172.16.12.4:636 [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection rese
t]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at ConnectActiveDirectory.main(ConnectActiveDirectory.java:39)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)

        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(Unknown Source)

        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.kickstart(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(Unknown
 Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Un
known Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source
)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.ldapBind(Unknown Source)
        ... 13 more
```

Code that am using is

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;

public class ConnectActiveDirectory {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"Administrator@mysite.com");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://172.16.12.4:636/cn=Users,dc=mysite,dc=com");
        try{
            java.io.InputStream in = new java.io.FileInputStream("C:\\client.crt");
            java.security.cert.Certificate c = java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(in);
            java.security.KeyStore ks = java.security.KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            ks.load(null);
            if (!ks.containsAlias("alias ldap")) {
                ks.setCertificateEntry("alias ldap", c);
            }
            java.io.OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream("C:\\keystorefile.jks");
            char[] kspass = "changeit".toCharArray();
            ks.store(out, kspass);
            out.close();        
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\keystorefile.jks");
        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        NamingEnumeration enm = ctx.list("");
        while (enm.hasMore()) {
            System.out.println(enm.next());
        }
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

does am doing any mistake?

where can i get good tutorial to do ssl connection with active directory ?

does http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Configuring+an+SSL+Certificate+for+Microsoft+Active+Directory site has correct steps to create and connect active directory with ssl?

could any on please help me.

Comment: this worked good when i restart my server. and http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Configuring+an+SSL+Certificate+for+Microsoft+Active+Directory link is a good tutorial.

Comment: An empty keystore won't contain any aliases, so testing for the presence of the alias is futile. And why your server certificate is being held in a file called `client.crt` is another mystery. And what is supposed to happen when the server certificate is renewed, another. This is poor technique.

Comment: Can you enable SSL debugging (e.g. -Djavax.net.debug=all) and collect more information on SSL handshake? That's the stage it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after my AD domain was renamed.  After reinstalling certificate services, you need to delete and re-issue the certificate issued to your Domain Controller.  Steps:

1. Open MMC
2. Add Snap In > Certificates > Computer > Local Computer
3. Navigate to Personal > Certificates
4. Delete any old certificates issued to this machine (in my case, these were issued by the old CA)
5. Right click on Certificates folder, click Request New Certificate.
6. Follow the steps to issue the new certificate to your domain controller.
7. Restart (not sure if this is necessary, but I restarted before it worked)

Answer (score -2):

I had the same error message using Atlassian Crowd and Active Directory over SSL. It is not applicable to this specific question, but when I tried to find out what was happening this thread was the first Google search hit, so I will write it down here.

In my case I first tested without SSL and then changed to SSL. Turns out I forgot to change the protocol used in the Crowd Connector settings.

Before: ldap://:389
After: ldaps://:636

Accidentally using ldap://:636 gave me the "Connection reset" error.

Comment: But the OP  is using ldaps:.