# LDAP Binds to AD Windows 2012 Failes LdapErr: DSID-0C090202 from Java (works in 2008)

Tags: java, ssl, active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2012

I am looking to query some account from active directory in java. I have currently the following environment which actually works in 2008 environments

```
objEnvironment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
objEnvironment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  strURL);
objEnvironment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
objEnvironment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, UserName);
objEnvironment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, Password);
objEnvironment.put("java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary", "objectGUID");
this.objLDAPContext = new InitialLdapContext(objEnvironment, null);
```

however when I try to use it on a 2012 AD I receive the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.AuthenticationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 8 - 00002028: LdapErr: DSID-0C090202, comment: The server requires binds to turn on integrity checking if SSL\TLS are not already active on the connection, data 0, v2580

I was looking for some answer on the web, but I did not find any with this particular code. I attempt changing the port to 636 but the same error was displayed. Do you have any idea of what could be happening?

Comment: "The server requires binds to turn on integrity checking if SSL\TLS are not already active on the connection" implies you must be using a secure connection to perform a bind. Try following the example at https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Using%20LDAPS%20With%20JNDI

Comment: I attempt to follow your example and the following error appears:

Comment: javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: fr.eurw.ey.net:389 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset]

Comment: I tried to follow this article to solve it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613767/connect-active-directory-with-the-support-of-ssl-ldaps
But a new error is displayed
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: <domain>:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty]

Comment: It appears you have not properly configured your Certificate store.